# What is Modal dialog in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is Modal dialog in Selenium Webdriver? If this type of dialog how to handle?

Please help me for finding the solution. I am using java as programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Modal dialog is any alert that pops up in your browser.

Usually you can do a `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();` or `accept();` and continue with your tests.

Answer (score 0):

The modal dialog corresponds to native modal windows in a browser which can be opened via javascript function `showModalDialog()` (have a look [here](http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-showmodaldialog-4-0-5-.aspx) for details on this function)